# birthday cake times twelve

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

I heard this in a [documentary about the Peoples Temple](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/transcript/jonestown-transcript/). The quote goes exactly:

> These people would be on time, they’d be polite and nice. They were a
>   span of ages, a span of races. They were tailor-made for a political
>   rally. To a politician, **it was like a birthday cake times twelve.**

Does it mean that these people would make a politician so happy that every month is like a birthday to them?

Comment: I would say that’s almost certainly what it is intended to mean. It’s similar to sayings like “Christmas come early” or “Christmas every day”. Those two are established phrases, whereas the one you quote here is not; possibly, it was a kind of pet phrase used by Marshall Kilduff (the speaker of the quote) or his group of friends—or perhaps he just made it up on the spot. But it is not a set phrase or an idiom.

Comment: This should be a chosen answer, not just a comment. Especially the examples are spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take such a phrase literally. Actually, the phrase **it was like a birthday cake times twelve** means that  happiness is so much that it can't be contained.

Comment: This is not an idiom. It’s just a one-off phrase (at least, according to Google, it appears in exactly two places: the documentary quoted, and this question), so you kind of have to take it literally and derive the meaning from that. In which case, aytug2001’s interpretation makes perfect sense and seems completely correct to me.

Comment: We don't know how often or for how long a period these rallies are held. So you can't quite say it's like having a birthday every month; it might be like having twelve birthdays at once. Or somewhere in between.

Comment: Indeed, "like all his birthdays came at once" is a fairly common (and much more elegant, I think) idiom in English meaning extreme delight. I would have said that "like a birthday cake times twelve" was perhaps a clumsy translation of a foreign idiom, but the author is Marshall Kilduff, a native of San Francisco who majored in English at Stamford.